# Круговая диаграмма с возможностью выбора секторов

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, svg

**Задача**
Местоположение – круг разделен на 8 частей + еще одна в центре итого 9. Каждая эта часть указывает на район Москвы, как говорят: “*Живу на 4 часа*” т.е. юго-восток или 6 часов - юг, а центр – это садовое кольцо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так как этот фильтр находиться внутри `form` и должен отправляться выбранная значения, в `html` получается 9 скрытых `radio` прикрепленным на `label`, 8 трапеции 1 круг в центре.

С бордером не получается, они перекрывает друг друга, так как они на самом деле прямоугольник, но со скрытыми краями.

Возможно ли сделать такую конструкцию на `CSS` или на чем угодно?

**Заранее спасибо!**

Comment: `svg` не предлагать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном случае не обязательно делать 9 радио кнопок. Достаточно будет одного скрытого инпута, а значения в него передавать из атрибута выбранного svg-элемента.

Я бы сделал так с использованием jQuery:

```js
var loc = $('#location');
$('.filter').on('click', function() {
  $('.filter').attr('class', 'filter');
  $(this).attr('class', 'filter active');
  loc.val($(this).attr('data-location'));
  console.log(loc.val());
});
```

```css
.filter {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: #d1d1d1;
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.filter:hover,
.filter.active {
  fill: #dcba89;
  stroke: #dcba89;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 66px!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="location">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="103.313" height="103.375" viewBox="0 0 103.313 103.375">
    <path class="filter" data-location="8" d="M51.661 51.688L15.309 15.336C25.347 5.297 37.464.278 51.661.278v51.41z"/>
    <path class="filter" data-location="7" d="M51.661 51.688H.25c0-14.197 5.02-26.314 15.058-36.353l36.353 36.353z"/>
    <path class="filter" data-location="6" d="M51.661 51.688L15.309 88.041C5.27 78.003.25 65.885.25 51.688h51.411z"/>
    <path class="filter" data-location="5" d="M51.661 51.688v51.41c-14.197 0-26.314-5.019-36.353-15.058l36.353-36.352z"/>
    <path class="filter" data-location="4" d="M51.661 51.688l36.353 36.353c-10.038 10.039-22.156 15.058-36.353 15.058V51.688z"/>
    <path class="filter" data-location="3" d="M51.661 51.688h51.41c0 14.196-5.019 26.314-15.058 36.353L51.661 51.688z"/>
    <path class="filter" data-location="2" d="M51.661 51.688l36.353-36.353c10.039 10.039 15.058 22.156 15.058 36.353H51.661z"/>
    <path class="filter" data-location="1" d="M51.661 51.688V.278c14.196 0 26.314 5.02 36.353 15.058L51.661 51.688z"/>
    <circle class="filter" data-location="9" cx="52" cy="52" r="20"/>
  </svg>
  <input type="hidden" id="location" />
</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Очень выручил... надо срочно изучить svg ))